# How to delay a loop using whatsapp-web.js it stops after loop

Tags: javascript, loops, foreach, async-await

```
 function readingFirebase(ref){
   ref.once('value').then(function(codes){
    
   
         codes.forEach  ( async function(nom){
             
            console.log('entrando a nombre de cada numero')
            await sleep(5000)
            const number = nom.val()['Celular'];                
            var chatId = number.toString().replace('+','') + "@c.us";
            var chatSinEspacios=chatId.replace(/\s/g,"")
            var chatSinEspaciosniComillas = chatSinEspacios.replaceAll('"',"")  
            client.sendMessage(chatSinEspaciosniComillas,mensajeAleman)               
            console.log('message sent to' ,chatSinEspaciosniComillas)
            ['Celular'].concat('@c.us')                   
                
        }) 
      })    
    }

 function sleep(ms) {
 return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
```

}

```
 readingFirebase(address/X)
```

The reading from the database is correct what is wrong is when I use the await sleep in the forEach after one round it stops sending just one message. As I need to send several messages to whatsapp numbers if they are too many Whatsapp blocks the number so I need at least a solution to send messages after some seconds for Whatsapp not to detect them and block them

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Now I edited anyway it is pretty clear the await sleep function just works one time then it stops.

Comment: foreach does not work with async. Use a for loop instead.

Comment: I love you Terry :)